# Passing a HiddenField value to a User Control in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a `HiddenField` which changes value depending on what the user clicks. On the same page I have an invisible `Panel` with a `User Control` inside of it. I want to pass this value to the control when the Panel becomes visible.

The code:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfdSelectedDeliveryAddressID" runat="server" Value="0" />
<asp:Panel ID="pnlOrder" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <uc3:AddressBook ID="AddressBook1" runat="server" AddressID="[value]" />
</asp:Panel>
```

I guess I'm asking what the syntax is to insert `$("#<%= hfdSelectedDeliveryAddressID.ClientID %>").val()` where "[value]" is. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Visible="false"` set, you must be going back to the server to set `Visible = true`, right?  When you set `Visible = true`, set the property as well:

```
AddressBook1.AddressID = hfdSelectedDeliveryAddressID.Value;
AddressBook1.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using jquery due to the fact you have

`$("#<%= hfdSelectedDeliveryAddressID.ClientID %>").val()`

You can use

```
var value = $("#<%= hfdSelectedDeliveryAddressID.ClientID %>").val();
$("#<%= AddressBook1.ClientID %>").attr("AddressID", value)
```

`.attr()` sets the attribute specified by the first parameter ("AddressID" in this case) with the value specified in the second parameter (the value of your hidden field in this case).

Hope it helps.